# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models.SecretBase'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-factory

I am developing an ETL solution using .NET and Azure Data Factory's `SqlServerLinkedService`  as part of data movement from on premise SQL Server to Azure.

I cannot set the password property as it's of type `SecretBase` which does not have any property/constructor:

[image]

does anyone know how to set this property?

Below is my code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, this only seems to be explained in [the Azure Python docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.SecretBase?view=azure-python)

> SecretBase class
>
> The base definition of a secret type.
>
> You probably want to use the sub-classes and not this class directly. Known sub-classes are: SecureString, AzureKeyVaultSecretReference

So you can use the [Azure SecureString implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.securestring?view=azure-dotnet) to set the value, as it inherits from `SecretBase`.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found solution using `SecureString` which is derived from `SecretBase` and has `Property` to set string value

[image]